# Name Styling Best Practices Internal/External variables/functions etc

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, remix

The solidity docs clearly specify how to style function order, types etc. However, are there an appropriate way to also separate between internal/external variables, functions etc. I see some people name internal functions and internal variables with a _prefix, others do it to function arguments as well which makes it a little confusing.